# Why MySQL Workbench creates more than two foreign keys for many to many relations?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench. I know that an additional table is needed to define a  many to many relation. But why sometimes workbench creates this table with more than two foreign keys?
Is it added managing performance issues?
How should I make queries with this structure?

For example this many to many relation is created automatically with three foreign keys:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `id` is the primary key for `pstx_project` then you definitely **don't** need `pstx_project_company_id` in your many to many breakdown table. As you say, these tables just need their related tables primary keys (in which it's composite will become it's own primary key), and a separate foreign key against each referenced table (*which might be composite* also, depending on the amount of columns from the referenced table's primary key), with the addition of other optional columns you might want to add.

If `company_id` was part of the primary key of `pstx_project` in some point, then it would make sense to include it in your many to many table. Maybe you edited the primary key at some point?

Remove `pstx_project_company_id` from your many to many table as it will bring you problems with consistency, as it would be redundant. Also make sure that `user_id` with `pstx_project_id` inside `user_has_pstx_project` is a primary key so it enforces non-duplicates.

As a side note, I also note a *loop* in your design: there are 2 ways to get to a company from a user. While loops are possible in some scenarios, please review if it's correct for your case as you might have another redundant link between user and company.

Comment: You're right. company_id is primary key. But is it needed to be primary? This column is created automatically too.
 Workbenck makes all foreign keys primary. What's the benefit?

Comment: @rostamiani Making the columns from the foreign keys a primary key in the many to many table is to enforce non-duplicates and also to speed up queries as primary keys in most (if not all) databases also creates an index by these columns. Check if the primary key on `pstx_project ` table is actually just `id` or if it also includes `company_id`.

Comment: both id and company_id are listed as primary keys and there is two indexes. on for both and one just for company_id. company_id is for a 1 to many relation not m2m. update: both are primary keys but just id is unique.

Comment: @rostamiani I believe you should change `pstx_project`'s primary key from (`id, company_id`) to (`id`), unless you can have the same project linked with several companies. Once you change this, recreate the many to many table and it will only consider `id` from project, and not `company_id`.

Comment: I found out why company_id is primary. to have a identifying relation between company and project tables, project.company_id should be primary kay. But why is it repeated in user_has_project table? see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762937/whats-the-difference-between-identifying-and-non-identifying-relationships

Comment: @rostamiani i don't think you need `company_id` on project table. If the project changes company and the primary key contains `company_id` then you will have to create a new row and delete the previous one, instead of just doing an update. You can have an identifying relationship just with a non-null foreign key, doesn't necessarily have to be part of the primary. That being said, when you create a m2m table, it needs **all columns for both primary keys**. If you still doubt that `company_id` isn't necessary then you realise it shouldn't be PK on `project`.